# Can I use a Chinese business visa (M) for tourism?

Tags: visas, china, tourist-visas, business-travel, change-purpose-of-travel

I have a valid multiple entry 60 day Chinese business visa that I use to travel for work. I am planing a trip to China that is only for vacation, can I use my business visa or do I need a tourist (L) visa also?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I or anyone I know went to China for work, we/I always entered in on a tourist visa. Usually, there's no distinction or separation between the two.

So with a business visa, you should be able to enter into the country and do some touring/sightseeing. Nothing really prevents from traveling around the country. Likewise, if you have a tourist visa, you can travel around and conduct some business.

Here's an excerpt from [this site](http://www.freechinavisa.org/china-visa-faq/what-is-the-difference-between-a-tourist-visa-and-a-business-visa.html) to confirm:

> Visas are issued to permit entry into a country for a specific purpose: to allow travel for leisure, or to conduct business activities. In general, 'tourist' visas are issued specifically for the purpose of travel for pleasure, while a 'business' visa generally permits a traveler to engage in normal business-related activities. You need a supporting letter to apply for business visa. However, there is no distinctive line between tourist visa and business visa. In another word, tourist visa will not prevent you from conducting business in China.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not completely correct. A business visa will allow you to legally conduct business, a tourist visa does not. Basically a business visa is better than a tourist visa.

Comment: That site is **not** an official site. However I do agree that generally the Chinese have historically had no issue with people entering under tourist visas to visit trade fairs, visit factories (buying) and the like. Of course that could change at any time, and if you are a Lotte salesman you might have rather more issues at the moment than a newly minted importer. Anyway, this doesn't really answer the question- I strongly suspect it's not a problem as @Belle implies, but I see no official evidence of it.

Comment: That some people use an L visa for business doesn't address the question of whether an M visa can be used for tourism.